# Firestore & Flutter Recurring Calendar Event

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a calendar feature in a Flutter app with the events stored as Documents in a Firebase Collection. Many of the events are recurring and need to repeat themselves every set period of time. What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `event_calendar` package for Flutter that supports [recurring events](https://pub.dev/packages/event_calendar/example):

> This package is for calculating calendar events with Reccurring events
> without the use of device calendar.

> Recurring events
>
> - Hourly
> - Daily
> - Weekly
> - Monthly (both from start of month and from last date)
> - Yearly